# Search for data which matches string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, entity-framework-core

I currently have a basic ASP.NET Core backend with CRUD operations (using EF Core). I want to add a search request now which receives a string from the frontend and looks for data matching the string.

I found [this article already](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search), however, since I have to create a `HttpGet` request, I can't get the routing to work.

This is how my Get Request for a single model looks like

```
// GET: api/JoeTests/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetJoeTest([FromRoute] int id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var joeTest = await _context.JoeTest.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (joeTest == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(joeTest);
}
```

Creating another Get Request like

```
[HttpGet("{string}")]
```

wont work. It will always jump into the GetID request. I could probably solve this if I use a different `RoutePrefix` for this search request instead of **api/JoeTests/**, however, is there no way to distinguish what exactly the frontend wants?

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/JoeTests")]
public class JoeTestsController : Controller
{
    private readonly CustomerDBContext _context;

    public JoeTestsController(CustomerDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
 }
```

These are the lines where I've defined the **base?** route

Comment: Are there any routing attributes on the controller which houses your action methods?

Comment: I'll edit the question since I cant get code to show up here

Comment: I don't think you can use both, when you're doing the _GET  api/JoeTests/5_ the code always interprets the first url match in the code so it always enter to the `{id}` instead of `{string}`, if you put the _GET string_ first it will  return the value of string. You have to use different routes to achieve that.

Comment: FYI: You can wrap code in back ticks('`') to make it look like the following: `public static void main()`. But you can't use newline characters (i.e. it will be across one line)

Comment: can you please let us know that what is inside GetID  method?

Comment: Do you want me to explain what GetID does? It receives a parameter with an ID and looks if what you passed is valid or not. Afterwards it looks for the model which matches your ID and returns it. Thats all it does

Comment: You don't need to post what `GetID` does, but you need to post the signature (i.e method with parameters and attributes but empty inside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with [route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-constraint-reference):

```cs
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/JoeTests")]
public class JoeTestsController : Controller
{
    // the :int restricts the route to integers
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetJoeTest([FromRoute] int id)
    {
    }

    // the route will match anything except integers
    [HttpGet("{str}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetJoeTest([FromRoute] string str)
    {
    }
}
```

It's also possible to change the route for each method:

```cs
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/JoeTests")]
public class JoeTestsController : Controller
{
    // route is now api/JoeTests/byid/5
    [HttpGet("byid/{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetJoeTest([FromRoute] int id)
    {
    }

    // route is now api/JoeTests/bystr/whatever
    [HttpGet("bystr/{str}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetJoeTest([FromRoute] string str)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW THANKS! This was what I needed :D